# Lightning renderAs="pdf" default save button

Tags: visualforce, pdf, canvas, renderas, publisher

I'm trying to create a PDF with a small preview. So using a visualforce page to show the pdf and using the default 'save' button.
When rendering the page without `renderAs="pdf"` and including the js `Sdfc.canvas.publisher` looks fine. The default save button is enabled.

```
<apex:page>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/canvas/sdk/js/publisher.js'></script>
<script> 
    Sfdc.canvas.publisher.subscribe({name: "publisher.showPanel",
                                     onData:function(e) {
                                         Sfdc.canvas.publisher.publish({name:"publisher.setValidForSubmit", payload:"true"});
                                     }});
    Sfdc.canvas.publisher.subscribe({ name: "publisher.post",
                                     onData: function(e) {
                                         save();
                                         Sfdc.canvas.publisher.publish({ name: "publisher.close",
                                                                        payload:{ refresh:"true" }});
                                     }}); 
</script>
</apex:page>
```

When adding `renderAs="pdf"` the `save` button is disabled. Any hint is appreciated.

--EDIT
To make clear which button I mean:
[image]

--EDIT 2
Maybe I missed that I'm opening the visualforce page via an `Action`, maybe there are better ways. I wanted to get a similar behavior to the default `Create PDF` button.

Comment: I think using the default buttons from the visualforce page are the most intuitive, then having them deactivated hanging around. I want to use that button to enable our Users to actually save the shown pdf as attachment.